# Unsure how to implement certain constraints and relations in this relational database schema

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am in the middle of designing the dB for school project- airline ticketing database.(Using MySQL workbench)

So far, I came up with the following design:
[image: database diagram]

Here are couple things I can't figure out:

1. Is it good idea to have Foreign keys as non-int values (such as `Varchar`) ??
2. Database needs to somehow keep track of Number of seats booked & Number of passengers on board for particular flight. Have no idea where to place those attributes.
3. How to make sure that Arrival City and Departure City (from `Flight` table) are different for particular flight ?

Comment: If you laid out your data elements and use normalization to the 3rd form, you will reach to your solution, everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Prefer `int`. Firstly it is better to have keys with shorter lengths. And later if you update a flight status, you can.

2- You can have `TotalSeats` in `Airplane` table and perhaps write an `SQL` query that by examining `Status`, you can figure out booked seats and passengers onboard.
(Consider schema improvements as suggested by @galuano1
3- You can write a trigger that makes sure they are not same, or perhaps validate it in the code.

Answer (score 5):

You get what you pay for on SO.  The advice against using natural keys (names instead of numbers, in this case) is common, but misguided.  If you don't believe me, ask your professor.

The number of seats would seem to be a property of the plane, right?  The number of booked seats would seem to be the count of seats booked, grouped by flight number.

The arrival and departure cities can be constrained with a `CHECK` constraint.  You might also want to ensure that departures happen before arrivals (assuming 21st century airport).

Your design is pretty good, better than some of the advice you're getting.  Stick with it, don't worry about datatypes for your keys, don't look for fanciness like triggers to implement application logic (and don't fob off real constraints to the application).  Do RTFM for `CREATE TABLE` several times.  If you think of a constraint that can't be declared, I suggest you document it in your project as a flaw in the DBMS.

Do think very carefully about what's unique.  I doubt you need BookingID, because PassengerID, Flight#, and Seat would seem to be unique.  Passengers are complex (in a real database you'd have a bunch of tables to describe someone) so they need an ID for convenient reference, but still you likely wouldn't want two records sharing name & address.

Comment: MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK() constraints. Sometimes, you can replace a CHECK() constraint with a foreign key constraint. (But not this time.) The only practical way to implement "arrival city is different from departure city" in MySQL is with a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

1. Varchar as foreign key : Bad idea
2. There is no point in having a table for just one column.(Booking Status)
3. Remove flight date and time from flight table, create a new table called flight_schedule, put it there.
4. Remove flight no foreign key from booking, use the aforesaid flight_schedule primary key as the foreign key.
5. Then use the flight_schedule key to find out no of seats booked from booking table
6. You can create a trigger to make sure the cities are different, but you can do that in application layer as well, because triggers are bad.

Comment: 2. How else are you going to force the constraints that only certain value from `Booking Status` table can appear in `Booking` table ???

Answer (score 1):

1) Keep the PK columns as `int`, with no business meaning, and also have a unique column with business meaning. This means FKs should be`int` as well. example:

```
 Flight Class
   class_id int PK 
   class_name varchar(15) Unique
```

2) You already have `Flight`, `Booking` and `Booking Status` tables with enough information to derive `number of bookings` and `passengers`, so there is no need to store these as separate columns.

3) To keep the Arrival/Departure data consistent, I would create a `Route` table with that data only and link to the `Flight` table; then create an insert/update trigger on `Route` table to make sure  Arrival/Departure Cities are different.